# Proof for integral absolute value inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

Thinking about this
$$\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\le\int_a^b|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx.$$

Why is this proof wrong? Be $f$ a continuous and integrable function, with primitive $F$, hence

$$\left|\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right| = \left|F(b) - F(a) \right| \leq \left|F(b) \right| - \left| F(a) \right| = \int_a^b \left| f(x) \right|\,\mathrm dx$$

Where I used the fact that $|a - b| = |a + (-b)| \leq |a| + |(-b)|$.

Comment: how do you justify the last equality?

Comment: $\left|F(b) - F(a) \right| \leq \left|F(b) \right| - \left| F(a) \right| $ is wrong.

Comment: @SineoftheTime Well I'm not able to...

Comment: @MartinR Yes, indeed take $F(b) = -3$ and $F(a) = 2$, we have $|-3-2| \leq |-3| - |2|$ that is $5 \leq 1$. A simple counterexample indeed...

Comment: Also $\left|F(b) \right| - \left| F(a) \right| = \int_a^b \left| f(x) \right|\,\mathrm dx$ is not true.

Comment: A simpler approach is to integrate the inequality $-|f(x) |\leq f(x) \leq |f(x) |$ over $[a, b] $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $a\leq b$ let the $x_0=a ,x_n=b $ choose $n-1$ points in $[a,b]$ and call them $x_2 ,x_3, \dots x_{n-1}$ such that $x_k > x_{k-1}$ then make the interval $I_k:= [x_{k-1}, x_k]$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$ define the norm of that partition by $|P|= \sup\limits_{k=1}^n \{ x_{k}- x_{k-1} \}$, from every interval $I_k$ choose any point and label it $t_k$  then we can define the integral $\int_a ^b f(t) dt $ if $\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0$ such that if $|P|<\delta$ then $\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1}) - L \right| < \epsilon  $ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$ that number $L $ is $\int_a ^b f(t) dt$ if $a> b $ we define $\int_a ^b f(t) dt=-\int_b ^a f(t) dt$ with that being said

$$\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(t_k)(x_{k}- x_{k-1}) \right| \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^n |f(t_k)|  (x_{k}- x_{k-1}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{by triangle inequality }$$

then  $\left|\int_a ^b f(t)  \right| \leq\int_a ^b |f(t)| dt$

Comment: Thank you! I came up with a similar proof in the meantime. But this points out a bunch of errors I made!